# Desejado aqui se refere a ser alvo?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

No seguinte texto, a palavra "o loiro desejado" significa "o cabelo loiro que a pessoa já tem, que é o alvo, pelo que a pessoa utilizará o produto" ou "o tipo de cabelo loiro que a pessoa deseja ter"?

Shampoo matizador que promove uma limpeza suave e combate os tons amarelados dos cabelos loiros, grisalhos, brancos, fios ou mechas em processos de descoloração. Suas propriedades nutritivas, antioxidantes, emolientes e revitalizantes, conferem maior maleabilidade, maciez e brilho radiante ao loiro desejado.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No texto o "loiro desejado" refere-se ao cabelo do qual o cliente já possui e deseja manter-lo com muito mais vida e beleza. Lembrando que a propaganda vale tanto para loiros NATURAIS como NÃO NATURAIS.

> Promove uma limpeza suave e combate os tons amarelados dos cabelos loiros, grisalhos, brancos, fios ou mechas em processos de descoloração.

Nesta primeira frase, a propaganda descreve mais os tipos de cabelos loiros NÃO naturais, portanto a ideia é justamente, combater os tons amarelados dos cabelos *não só* loiros como, grisalhos, brancos, fios, ou mechas em processo de descoloração.

> Suas propriedades nutritivas, antioxidantes, emolientes e revitalizantes, conferem maior maleabilidade, maciez e brilho radiante ao loiro desejado.

Nesta segunda frase é um "jaba" a favor do produto, dizendo que o *shampoo matizador* trará maior maleabilidade, maciez e brilho ao loiro (que você já possuí) desejado.

Comment: Obrigada!! Aprecio sua ajuda e seu tempo.